# Merge PointData from multiple files in Paraview

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, paraview

I am tasked with combining multiple files in Paraview for a representation.
To be precise, I have a .vtk file that defines the whole mesh structure, which works fine. I have a second file (text-based, e.g. csv) with a single value per line, where each line is a PointData value, i.e.:

```
[PointData[0]]
[PointData[1]]
[PointData[2]]
[...]
[PointData[n-1]]
```

I tried playing around with programmable sources and filters, but couldn't get it to work. I would appreciate your help. I hope the description was clear, but I added a picture of the setup to clarify the situation.

[image: problem setup]

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. You have a file with the mesh and another file (csv) with another values, maybe scalar values of the mesh points. If it is this, have you tried to add the so-called scalar points from csv to the vtk file? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. Adding the points to the vtk file is maybe possible, but the vtk file is in binary format and I was looking for a pure paraview solution since I have this problem on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

- Open ParaView
- Open your .vtk file containing the geometry, apply
- Open your .csv file containing the data, Applpy
- Add a **TableToPoints** filter on the csv file, Check **"Keep All Data Arrays"**, Apply
- Select the vtk file in the pipeline browser (**very important to select it first**)
- Press ctrl and select also the TableToPoints in the pipeline browser
- Add a **AppendAttributes** filters, apply
- The output of the AppendAttributes contains your geometry and your data

Comment: Thanks, but this just works for me if the .csv file has X, Y, Z and PointData for each point. If it only has PointData, it will create points with coordinates that are equal to the PointData. The resulting mesh can not be colored using PointData.

Comment: Make sure you, Check "Keep All Data Arrays" and you select the .vtk file first.

Comment: What if I have a series of (time-dependent) vtk files and I would like to append to it a csv. file, which contains a time-dependent universal variable? (by universal variable, I mean a variable that is represented by only a number at each time-step)

Comment: open your own topic please